# How to make each value in a Record have an independent type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure how I can fix this interface so that each "Route" can have an independent template param, different from the other entries in the map:

```
export type RouteMap = {
    [k in string]: Route<any>  
}
```

Here I don't really want specify `any`, I want it to be inferred. Is there some way to say that each entry should be a `Route<something>` but the `<something>` can be different for each?

Here's a [minimal example of TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgFkCGYcAvHAN4CwAUHLXANoDWcAlgHZwDOMU7A5gF0AXOiw4APPjaIAfLQD08uOIC0auAAkIAdzgATCHACScAGYsQCABYtOXQzCv54wfAGMro7KjdTWbU2Aoa1QkFDMoCABbELgAVV4AFWAosAAbZ2BxRORgOQB+agBfampQSFh-HChTd1QMb3EABThQHDY9OwSWJvwofCjOOUoaOhxUjJwRbuSJzOaZUtHaPmAYfJENKT00oIXqOjhIbg3Nbd2ofaoSqiXy6Hgw1G7e-sGSdGA3aD1xbl42HwADTxKBpV4DABq+DSmDyAG5qE84E1eFEWDAWAA3VCkf78OAAHzgbEwUQARkEiXByRAILs-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-GKwJhTIRQyNmADk8h2WkEBkPk+YAFRFDFnZArRhz4JwiBsG4cCrDAuYFjWh5qTlzmHIocAAAZ5vm9VcF+mBpIOlL+IEUB5oOeVwHu5b5pWMDiAFQhBT8fxMeFs2RRONW0DchzaVwzi2OYh5eDg6pAA) that should compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is only able to infer generic type parameters in functions. So you can use a simple function that just returns its argument, while also constraining that argument's type with a generic type argument, to force TypeScript to do this sort of inference:

```js
export type RouteMap<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [R in keyof T]: Route<T[R]>;
}

// TypeScript can only infer generic types using function parameters
function routeMap<T extends Record<string, any>>(arg: RouteMap<T>) { return arg; }

export interface Route<P extends UriParams> {
    template: UriTemplate<P>

    get?: Handler<P>
    post?: Handler<P>
}


export type UriParams = Record<string, UrlParamValue>;
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null;
type PrimitivePair = [key: string, value: Primitive];
type PrimitiveMap = {
    [K in string]: Primitive;
};
export type UrlParamValue = Primitive | Primitive[] | PrimitivePair[] | PrimitiveMap;

export type Handler<P extends UriParams> = (req: BunRequest<P>, res: HybridResponse) => void | Promise<void>

type HybridResponse = unknown

interface BunRequest<P extends UriParams> {
    headers: Headers
    method: unknown
    url: BunUrl<P>
    body: unknown
}


interface BunUrl<P extends UriParams> extends URL {
    params: P
    path: string
}

export class UriTemplate<P extends UriParams> {
   constructor(template: string) {
    //
   }
}

////////////////////////////////

const routes = routeMap({
    hello: {
        template: new UriTemplate<{q:Record<string,string>}>('/hello{?q*}'),
        async get(req, res) {
              // `req` is inferred as BunRequest<{q:Record<string,string>}>
        }
    }
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgFkCGYAPACpyg4B2AJgM7rADG01RtMUAlpQOYA0cfJUQA+EXAC8cAN4BYAFBwlcANpo43OAGtgiCADM4JALoAudFhyk1xkQG4FAXwUKA9K6PJgAZUZcw8IxCcBCUADaIGpT6wFBwPMCUsZyMCF70mLTcPHD6mJSMMJyhcGD4UPgAtsA4ULQKeQVFJVCWeISk5CBUdAzMUKzsXLwCQqIiABTlPOYY2O3EJCIAlDJwUDWYUJSCUDx2cM7yCqCQsFG1+viMqHNWAApdPfQAqlz35VW04nKKyjiVMBhfA4cxvTgkYCA4EPEQuP5KBIwAD85gAEkJqGFYkR7nCEaUIOxUXAMTRsVBcfijvDTtB4EgUHBwR8KpV6FI0EwWGwONkBG8wqyqgA1fBhTDAewKRmoe5cSqcIoAN1QUiG2TgAB84JRMJUAEaxbVwA0QCDY4I6vVhMIOeSyuDyziKlXAD6cOJSFQ6RDmDUjODK8WS8zO12cVXGe2O8NKyMLSQyBTKVQAaSicADPDMToV8dV9sc9rp50dguFlTFErVeZdBdQOrjbpUxhNzYTHqgrfb+bdBDA9pO4HpaSZZKxOMeFESvRZn3Z4ikEw2AEdzAAhfJc1eS9hUgQbWjoxAGrjULm0SCUWjAVYScTKiCcai9iCK29EJ8v-Eyryk09z0va9byTfItEoCAAHdKHhbhLmuVAt0oHc9xgXEnlnV53gXb5kwJAALYB8GoWJj1JYjSLqFNlGqGACIgahzHAyCYJopQtjCTd8kFKl2NNRi-TgFjoNg+QaWOeR4NiK4bjgZDeOnbosOZHC2TwmcaFeNAABl8NTMp1LDfiyno-0+V4JxaRHc5GGBWhsIhKEgRBYAMM0uc1K+H52OYG8OEwQpoAmAEXNBLMLJ4VZflTdx2KOCT3CS5KUtStKUvhPz2HWNoORy+YBwmGLlCI20IHMYrUyUUKYWAcwkig1SnOhVyiGkdcuX6QZIr4bMREcSYAHJXFKsIIGkZFVwAKkcQblj4fjU3wWhEAKeIahXYBV0PYBaGixaqtijwAAM12OjR6G4GIoA2V9lvk7ctrQtqOu5AZeWGfg+oGg6lCOVMEuWOwgA)

As you can see, in order to make use of this inference you need to use the `routeMap` function to wrap your object literal when declaring it, in order for TypeScript to infer its type correctly.

Comment: That's not bad actually. Then I don't need `satisfies` or `const routes: RouteMap`. So same number of keystrokes but better typing. Thank you!